# In Linq to Sql how can I get the Id of row when creating new entry

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello guys I have a Sql table with Id which is incremented. What I am doing is Uploading images either via external link or file upload using a model and saving the imagefile in my file system and then saving the Filename into my database. My dilemma is that when saving the file **I want to name it with a suffix of its Id** on my database. But I get the Id as 0 everytime. Also is there anyway of making the two actions of Saving to file system and saving to database interdependent so that if one fails then other one fails as well. I dont want to bore you so you I have kept the code short.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Media] (
[Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Link] NVARCHAR (500) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The View model and Database model look like

```
public class Post
{
  //[Key] *Commented code is present in dbcontext model
  //[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  //public int Id { get; set; }
  // public string Link { get; set;} link to my filesystem
  public string ExternalLink { get; set; }//gets saved on my filesystem
  public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }//gets saved on my filesystem
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

My controller action looks like this

```
 ....Get the image in Sytem.Drawing.Image class called Img
 string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Imgs/");
 Img.Save(path); //dont want to save as path but as Path + Title + _Id.jpg
 db.MediaSet.Add(mediat);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get the ID until after you have saved the row. It is not possible to predict what ID you will get, even for an identity column because someone may insert a row right after you query but before you insert.

So, save the row first, then get the ID and save the file. If the file operation fails, (catch all exceptions), delete the row.